# Alternative channel:entries Depending on First Result Set

Tags: channel-entries, stash

I have two channels: products and promos. I need to display either one or the other on my homepage. If I find a promo, I display that one and not the the product. If I don't find a promo, I display the product.

I have Stash installed. I'm thinking I try for the promo. If I find it, I set a Stash variable called promo_found to TRUE; otherwise its FALSE. Then I can test for promo_found == FALSE, and do the products channel:entries call.

Would this work? (I don't have much/any experience with Stash.) Is there a better pattern to use?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use Stash, you could just do it with `no_results` and an embed.

Homepage template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="promos" ...}
  {if no_results}
    {embed="product"}
  {/if}

  <div id="promo">
     ...
     {promo_content}
     ...
  </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Product embed template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" ...}
  <div id="product">
    ...
    {product_content}
    ...
  </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```